# echo and return print different values

Tags: php, int, return, echo, bcmath

I am working on php `bcmath` extention for factorial calculation and i find that    `echo` and  `return`  cause different result

This Code generate wrong result

```
<?php
    $a = 25;
    function test($a){
        if($a>1){
        $sum   =   bcmul($a, test($a-1)) ;
            echo $sum;
        } 
       if($a == 1) { return $a ;}
    }
    test($a);   // Output  200000000000000000000000
    ?>
```

while below code generate correct result

```
<?php 
$a = 25;
function test($a){
    if($a>1){
    $sum   =   bcmul($a, test($a-1)) ;
        return $sum;
    } 
   if($a == 1) { return $a ;}
}
echo test($a);

?>
```

this problem generate `200000000000000000000000` result with  `echo $sum` and return wrong result but if i `echo test()` and `return $sum` then it tend to right result `15511210043330985984000000`. why

Comment: `return` ends the function, `echo` doesn't?

Comment: actually it's not about the difference between echo and return, it's just because you are using recursion into your function so you have to return the intermediate results

Answer (score 1):

Please use the latter version with `return` and `echo test()` because you are using [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) (see the line with `test($a-1)`). Recursion only works correctly when using *return statements* which pass the interim results back to next higher level level in the stack.

echo on the other hand doesn't return the interim results to be calculated further - it just prints them out.